# regex syntax in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a log file like this

```
[01012017 052235 500][1][INFO]> ----Amount   : 200

[01012017 052235 515][1][INFO]> ----Mix      : 1

[01012017 052235 515][1][INFO]> ----Currency : LKR

[01012017 052243 156][1][INFO]> ----Denomination

[01012017 052243 171][1][INFO]> -----CU  TYP
```

I want to extract the date after the 1st square bracket and I wrote a python code as follows.

```
transactionDate = re.findall('\[(.*?)\s\w+\s\w+\]\[\w\]\[INFO\]\>\s+\w+Amount',strtosearch2,re.DOTALL)
```

This gives a empty list. The expected output is:

```
01012017
```

Can you please help fix this error ?

Comment: can you provide the expected output ?

Comment: 01012017 here it is!

Comment: Why not `\[(\d{8})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the following:

```
re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\s\d+\s\d+\]\[\d\]\[INFO\]\>', str2search)
```

Note that I'm using `\d` (which matches digits) instead of `\w` (which matches any "word" characters)

Also, this solution will work for every line in your log file, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `"\[(.*?)\s\w+\s\w+\]\[\w\]\[INFO\]\>\s+\w+Amount"` has one mistake in it, the `\w+` before `Amount`,  since you were trying to match `----` with `\w+`, but a dash (`-`) is not in the `\w` character set.

You will need to change that part of the regex to include the dash, so making a set `[\w-]+` should solve your problem.

---

The final regex will be `"\[(.*?)\s\w+\s\w+\]\[\w\]\[INFO\]\>\s+[\w-]+Amount"`

When you use this regex, you will get your desired output:

```
['01012017']
```